# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Desktop Background Compression

Tags: 18.04, screen, desktop-background, compression, jpeg

I hope some of you can help. I recently took a nice photo and decided I would like it as my desktop background. The image is around 4000x2200 pixels and is in ratio with my monitor.

When I view the image in image viewer, there is no issue. However after setting it to my background I instantly notice harsh lines in the subject of the image.

Does anyone know how to set the background to not compress the image when set as my desktop or lock screen background?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure how one could change the algorithm used by the desktop to scale images, but as a workaround, you could scale the image file in for example Gimp to the pixel size of your monitor.

Comment: Now I feel stupid :) That worked, making the image the same size in pixels to my screen fixed it. Thanks for the suggestion!